# Pressing enter key in rich:suggestionBox in IE causes SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I've a JSF page

```
 <a4j:form id="form1">
   <h:inputText id="input1"></h:inputText>
   <rich:suggestionBox suggestionAction="someAction" for="input1">
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" />
    </h:column>
   <f:param value="someValue" name="someName"></f:param>
  </rich:suggestionBox>
  <a4j:commandLink id="link1" action="#{someBean.someAction}" reRender="form1"/>
 </a4j:form>
```

Command link is set as default action for Enter Key.
If I input the value in inputTextbox and press enter, without letting the suggestionbox to draw, the jquery script error appears in the status bar of ie 8.

I tried to resolve it by removing re-rendering of form1, it was resolved or if I let the suggestion box to draw and then hit Enter.
Is there any solution that I don't need to remove re-rendering of form1.

error:

```
faces/a4j/g/3_3_1.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js
SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. 
jquery.js, line 423 character 143
```

Comment: Probably a bug in jQuery, what's on line 423?

Comment: var box=this[0].getBoundingClientRect(),doc=this[0].ownerDocument,body=doc.body,docElem=doc.documentElement,clientTop=docElem.clientTop||body.clientTop||0,clientLeft=docElem.clientLeft||body.clientLeft||0,top=box.top+(self.pageYOffset||jQuery.boxModel&&docElem.scrollTop||body.scrollTop)-clientTop,left=box.left+(self.pageXOffset||jQuery.boxModel&&docElem.scrollLeft||body.scrollLeft)-clientLeft;return{top:top,left:left};}

Comment: Looks like [#4996](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4996) then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems to be bug in the script behind suggestion box.
I just make a workaround by setting timeout of 1 second on hotkey("return").
This gives time to scripts behind suggestion box to complete their processing so that after 1 second, action on return key can process flawless.